# Typescript build options on Console app

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, amd, web-essentials

I want to create web app on `TypeScript`, wich hosted in console app (`NancyFx` self host).
When i create class `ASP.NET Web Application` in project properties i can select AMD module system. But in cosole app i can't see this page.

[image]

Also in Web Essetials (v 2.5.3) there is no this settings too.

[image]

How i can enabled this option directly without adding `///<amd... />` in each file.

Comment: Not sure why down voted. Learning a language from console app is best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution: in `ProjectName.csproj` just add

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'">
   <TypeScriptModuleKind>amd</TypeScriptModuleKind>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Were you able to execute the typescript app from console application?

Comment: its simply to do via Nodejs